# Interval tree usage to find out overlapping regions

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I am trying to use interval tree to solve this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/x-and-his-shots). Below is my try but understandably it is not working i.e. it is not returning all the intervals.

A cricket match is going to be held. The field is represented by a 1D plane. A cricketer, Mr. X has  favorite shots. Each shot has a particular range. The range of the ith shot is from A(i) to B(i). That means his favorite shot can be anywhere in this range. Each player on the opposite team can field only in a particular range. Player  can field from A(i) to B(i). You are given the  favorite shots of Mr. X and the range of M players.

Brute force solution is timing out for some of the test cases. All I need is an idea.

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.highest = high
        self.low = low
        self.high = high

class interval:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.count = 0

    def add_node(self, node):
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = node
        else:
            if self.head.highest < node.high:
                self.head.highest = node.high         
            self.__add_node(self.head, node)

    def __add_node(self, head, node):                   
        if node.low <= head.low:         
            if head.left == None:            
                head.left = node
            else:            
                if head.left.highest < node.high:
                    head.left.highest = node.high
                self.__add_node(head.left, node)
        else:           
            if head.right == None:                
                head.right = node
            else:               
                if head.right.highest < node.high:
                    head.right.highest = node.high          
                self.__add_node(head.right, node)

    def search(self, node):
        self.count = 0
        return self._search(self.head, node)

    def _search(self, head, node):
        if node.low <= head.high and node.high >= head.low:
            self.count += 1 
        print(self.count, head.high, head.low)        
        if head.left != None and head.left.highest >= node.low:
                return self._search(head.left, node)
        elif head.right != None:
                return self._search(head.right, node)       
        return self.count

data = input().split(" ")
N = int(data[0])
M = int(data[1])
intervals = interval()
for i in range(N):
    data = input().split(" ")
    p = node(int(data[0]), int(data[1]))
    intervals.add_node(p)
count = 0
for i in range(M):  
    data = input().split(" ")
    count += intervals.search(node(int(data[0]), int(data[1]))) 
print(count)
```

Comment: There's an easier solution than interval trees that requires only sorting and binary search. Try to think if you could somehow query how many shot ranges start before fielding range ends and how many shot ranges end before fielding range starts

Comment: @niemmi: it will be almost as worse as 0(n) because of the fact that even when lower bound is less, higher bound can have the entire field.

Comment: True, it's worse than O(n). To be exact it's O(n log n + m log n) where n is the number of shots and m is the number of players. It's still fast enough to pass all the test cases.

Comment: @niemmi: I fail to understand why are you taking log(n) for single player search? It would be nice if you can post your answer as one of the answer with a example and then i can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving the problem is to realize that there's no need to compare single fielding range to a single shot range since only the total number intersecting ranges needs to be known. In order to achieve this in O(n log n) time following algorithm can be used.

Take the shot ranges and create two ordered lists: one for start values and another for end values. The example problem has shots `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]` and after the sorting we have two lists: `[1, 2, 4, 6]` and `[2, 3, 5, 7]`. Everything so far can be done in O(n log n) time.

Next process the outfield players. First player has range `[1, 5]`. When we do binary search with start value `1` to sorted end values `[2, 3, 5, 7]` we notice that all the shot ranges end after the start value. Next we do another search with end value `5` to sorted start values `[1, 2, 4, 6]` we notice that `3` shot ranges start before or at the end value. Then we do simple calculation `3 - 0` to conclude that first outfield player can intersect `3` ranges. Repeating this to all outfield players (M) takes O(m log n) time.

Comment: @nomanpouigt: By not working you mean it gives wrong results or it's too slow? I read the code and ran it couple times with different inputs, it gave me same results as my implementation that passes all the tests. The only problem I see is that it's too slow, you need to sort both `high` & `low` and then do binary search on them instead of sequential. Check [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html) in case you don't feel like writing the search yourself.

Comment: it fails all test cases and in some cases times out. I will try to use what you said but can you post your solution in hackerrank and see if it passes all test cases ?

Comment: @nomanpouigt I've posted it and it passes all test cases. Of course I didn't do any extensive testing between two of the solutions, just took the example input, changed it a bit and checked if both solutions yield the same result.

Comment: possible to post it in ideone.com so that I can compare it?

Answer (score 1):

I did some homework and tried to solve it with interval tree.But as you have realized,traditional interval tree may not be suitable for this problem.This is because there is only one match returned when searching an interval tree,but we need to find all matches.More exactly,we just need to count all matches,it's not required to find all of them.

So I add 2 fields to your node for the sake of pruning.I'm not familiar with python,It looks like this in java:

```
 static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    Node left;//left child
    Node right;//right child
    int low;//low of current node
    int high;//high of current node
    int lowest;//lowest of current subtree
    int highest;//highest of current subtree
    int nodeCount;//node count of current subtree

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        return low - o.low;
    }
}
```

In order to make an balanced tree,I sort all the intervals and then build the tree from middle to both sides recursively(It may be better to use red-black tree).This affects a lot to performance,so I suggest to add this feature to your program.

The preparations have been finished so far.The search method looks like this:

```
  private static int search(Node node, int low, int high) {
    //pruning 1: interval [low,high] totally overlaps with subtree,thus overlaps with all children
    if (node.lowest >= low && node.highest <= high) {
        return node.nodeCount;
    }
    //pruning 2: interval [low,high] never overlaps with subtree
    if (node.highest < low || node.lowest > high) {
        return 0;
    }

    //can't judge,go through left and right child

    //overlapped with current node or not
    int c = (high < node.low || low > node.high ? 0 : 1);
    if (node.left != null) {
        c += search(node.left, low, high);
    }
    if (node.right != null) {
        c += search(node.right, low, high);
    }
    return c;
}
```

There are 2 main prunings as the comments show.There is no need to go through the children when the current subtree is totally overlapped or never overlapped.

It works well in most conditions and has been accepted by the system.It costs about 4000ms to solve the most complicate test case(N=99600,M=98000).I'm still trying to do more optimization,hoping to be helpful.